# Why does `cd ~"/mydata"` succeed while `cd ~/"mydata"` not

Tags: bash, quoting, bash-expansion

Why does the first command fail, while the second succeeds?

```
$ cd ~"/mydata"
bash: cd: ~/mydata: No such file or directory

$ cd ~/"mydata"
```

Answer (score 5):

The way *tilde expansion* works is that *tilde prefix* consists of the `~` plus all the characters before the first unquoted slash, or to the end of the word if there is no unquoted slash. Then the substitution which happens depends on the tilde prefix; `~`, `~-` and `~+` are special cases, otherwise the `~` is stripped and the rest of the characters are considered a username. See `man bash` (or the manual page of your shell if that shell is not Bash).

- In `~"/mydata"` the tilde is followed by a *quoted* slash and thus the tilde prefix is `~/mydata`; since there is no user account named `/mydata` the tilde prefix won't be replaced and the shell will be looking for a directory named literally `~/mydata` and it won't find it.
- In `~/"mydata"` the tilde is followed by a an unquoted slash and thus the tilde is replaced with the contents of `$HOME` if `HOME` is set, otherwise with the name of the home directory of the user (taken from `/etc/passwd`); the shell will be looking for a directory name like `/home/`username`/mydata`.